# Laravel. MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel

There is a 2 language version on the site, when you turn on Rus the language is added to the URL "/ru" ie it will be http://site/ru, but at the same time, all attempts to send the form end with an error - "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php", in the original languages ​​http://site form Normally Are working

My forms:

```
<form action="/callback" method="post">



 Route::post('/callback', 'ApiController@callback');
```

Comment: Any other method than POST is not allowed, you probably are sending a get request to that /callback route. Change it to Route::get and try again.

Comment: @Frondor but i have <form method="post">

Comment: Are you sure that form is under `/callback` route? Otherwise, you must specify it on the `action` attribute: `<form method="POST" action="/callback">`.

Comment: At this point i want to hint on a general problem depending on the browser: Please keep in mind that there is a small difference between chrome and firefox 'cause firefox does NOT add an extra slash at the end of an called url; chrome does. Keep that in mind during development. This caused many errors on my actual dev page. Im still nor sure if laravel make a difference at this point (during resolving a route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By registering that route, you're explicitly asking for a POST request, any other method is not allowed.

If you can't control the incoming request's method, then you should try using
`Route::get` or `Route::any` (I wouldn't recommend the last one if you're creating an API).

If you are confused about how routes work, I recommend you to use named routes, so you're always sure you're pointing the form to the right direction:

```
Route::post('/callback', 'ApiController@callback')->name('api.callback');
```

And then use it for your form in the view just like

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('api.callback') }}">
```

Or if you don't want to give it a name, just use the `action` helper

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('ApiController@callback') }}">
```

Comment: The last option(::any) works, but why it is not desirable to use it?

Comment: @ByArper so you have more control over your routes, not really a security risk or something like that, but I always want to have control over which routes I'm exposing.